# How to fix the "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher" error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, aes

I'm using a Spring Boot application with an attribute converter class to encrypt certain fields of entities when persisting in the database and decrypt them when retrieving the data. I use @Convert(converter = DataEncryptionConverter.class) annotation on the fields of entities that I want to encrypt/ decrypt. Here is my code:

```
@Converter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    //    @Value("${encryption.key}")
    private String encryptionKey = "secret-test-key1";
    private final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    private final String encryptionCipher = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    private Key key;
    private Cipher cipher;

    private Key getKey() {
        if (key == null) {
            key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        }
        return key;
    }

    private Cipher getCipher() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        if (cipher == null) {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionCipher);
        }
        return cipher;
    }

    // initilize cipher into the memory -- decides whether we want to encrypt or decrypt data with the cipher
    private void initCipher(int encryptMode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        getCipher().init(encryptMode, getKey(), ivParameterSpec);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(attribute);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getCipher().doFinal(bytes));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        initCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = getCipher().doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData));
        return SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    }
}
```

If I call the method convertToDatabaseColumn explicitly to encrypt my existing plain data in the database, it works fine.

```
@Test
    public void encryptTeam() {
        DataEncryptionConverter converter = new DataEncryptionConverter();

        List<Team> teams = teamRepository.findAll();
        for (Team team : teams) {
            team.setTeamName(converter.convertToDatabaseColumn(team.getTeamName()));
            team.setTeamDesc(converter.convertToDatabaseColumn(team.getTeamDesc()));
        }
        teamRepository.saveAll(teams);
    }
```

If I call the method convertToEntityAttribute to decrypt the encrypted data in the database, it works fine.

```
@Test
    public void decryptTeam() {
        DataEncryptionConverter converter = new DataEncryptionConverter();

        List<Team> teams = teamRepository.findAll();
        for (Team team : teams) {
            team.setTeamName((String) converter.convertToEntityAttribute(team.getTeamName()));
            team.setTeamDesc((String) converter.convertToEntityAttribute(team.getTeamDesc()));
        }
        teamRepository.saveAll(teams);
    }
```

If I call the repository methods explicitly in the code to save/ get data, it works fine but when the application is running, many functionalities work fine but at some or the other place a JPA repository method throws the "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16" exception and it is not able to decrypt.

For example here this method defined in User Repository is throwing an exception:

User findByPrimaryEmail(String primaryEmail);

Error:

```
Apr 12, 2023 6:49:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    

Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.prepareInputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1005)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:848)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at com.tse.core_application.configuration.DataEncryptionConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(DataEncryptionConverter.java:70)
    at com.tse.core_application.configuration.DataEncryptionConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(DataEncryptionConverter.java:22)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Earlier I was using only "AES" as the transformation string and I was getting the same error so I changed it to "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" but I still got the same error. Then I added the IvParameterSpec as well but I'm still getting these errors.

Comment: Is there any possibility that some of the data was encrypted with a different key? I have seen this misleading error messages in such cases. Try to print out the failed encrypted value (probably as base64 encrypted) and use that value to test the decrypter in isolation.

Comment: This exception only depends on the size of the input data, so any error will be outside of this code. Doing terrible things like using `"AES"` as algorithm string or putting `Cipher` in a field (a stateful object) shows clearly that you don't really know what you are doing. Ask an expert, take a course, but please don't go and create *secure* code while just testing if it works or not.

Comment: All data is encrypted with the same key. I've not changed the key at any time. In Isolation, it works fine and error is not always on this repository method, sometimes it works fine and some other repository method fails. Could the issue be related to concurrency or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to using the same cipher every time which was causing the concurrency issue. I was able to solve this by modifying the code to create a new cipher every time it is called:

```
@Converter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    // @Value("${encryption.key}")
    private String encryptionKey = "secret-test-key1";
    private final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    private final String encryptionCipher = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    private Key createKey() {
        return new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    }

    private Cipher createCipher() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        return Cipher.getInstance(encryptionCipher);
    }

    // Initialize cipher into the memory -- decides whether we want to encrypt or decrypt data with the cipher
    private Cipher initCipher(int encryptMode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Cipher cipher = createCipher();
        Key key = createKey();
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(encryptMode, key, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Cipher cipher = initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(attribute);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(bytes));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Cipher cipher = initCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData));
        return SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    }
}
```